# How can I access object nested properties from Swift debugger

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for iOS library to load an array of children from the database.

I am storing the `snap.value` in a `NSMutableDictionary` as follows:

```
var list=NSMutableDictionary()
let students = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("students") 
students.observe(.childAdded) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        self.list[snap.key] = snap.value
 }
```

When I put a breakpoint at the last line, I can examine the contents of `list` variable, and it successfully contains all 8 children from firebase.

[image]

from the debugger, I tried this:

```
(lidb) po list.count
>> 8
```

So I tried to retrieve the name/age from element 3 by typing:

```
(lidb) po list[3]
>> nil

(lidb) po list[3]["value"]["name"]
>> error: <EXPR>:3:8: error: type 'Any?' has no subscript members

(lldb) po (list[3] as? Dictionary<String,Any?>)
>> nil

(lldb) po (list[3] as? Dictionary<String,Any?>)["value"]
>> nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a dictionary, so you should access it using the key, not the index (despite the debugger showing the indexes making it seem like an array).

Comment: but I want to iterate through all of the items in the dictionary without having to use the key.. is there a way?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should be able to do so with `for (key, value) in dict) {...}`